# Android LruCache and Animationdrawable

Tags: android

i have a Activity and in this Activity i do a animation. 
But a have a Memory leak, then i use LruCache.

My Question is how a can set the images from the LruCache in my animation?

Comment: Please add details to your question, it is difficult to help you right now with such little information.

Answer (score 0):

LruCache:

```
private LruCache<Integer, Bitmap> mBitmapCache;

public final static Integer[] resIdList = new Integer[] {
        R.drawable.image0, R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2,
        R.drawable.image3, R.drawable.image4, R.drawable.image5,
        R.drawable.image6, R.drawable.image7, R.drawable.image8,
        R.drawable.image10};


private void initializeCache() {

    final int memClass = ((ActivityManager)getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE)).getMemoryClass();

    mCache = new LruCache<Integer, Bitmap>(1024 * 1024 * (memClass / 4)) {

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap value) {
            return value.getByteCount();
        }
    };

    int imgId = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < resIdList.length; i++) {
        imgId = resIdList[i];
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), pingImgResId);
        mBitmapCache.put(pingImgResId, bitmap);
    }
```

Comment: img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animation);
        AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) img.getBackground();
        frameAnimation.start();

Comment: How i can get the images for animation??

Comment: Is this your answer or your problem?